# Resque mailer systemSTackerror to deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, mandrill

I am trying to use Resque::Mailer on my NotificationMailer

```
class NotificationsMailer < MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer
include Resque::Mailer

default from: 'myemail@gmail.com', from_name: 'Alex'

def create_client to
  mandrill_mail template: 'beta-sign-up-confirmation',
              subject: 'create a client',
              to: to,
              inline_css: true
end
end
```

When I call the deliver

```
NotificationsMailer.create_client('myemail@gmail.com').deliver
```

I am getting the following error

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
from /Users/myname/.rvm/src/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/resque_mailer-2.2.7/lib/resque_mailer.rb:39:in  `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm think you can't do this. `MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer` is not a subclass of `ActionMailer::Base`, which is requirement for `resque_mailer`. To be more precise, `resque_mailer` needs method-level compatibility, which is not met.